# Spring Cloud - How to get host and port of a service dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a system of microservices that is set up with docker compose, it contains a emailService and an userService that are conected with eureka and gateway service. The docker-compose.yml  like this:

```
  eureka-service:
    image: app/eureka-server

  gate-way-service:
    image: app/gate-way-service
    ports:
      - "8050:8050"
    links:
      - mysqldb
      - eureka-service
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=compose

  user-service:
    image: app/user-service
    links:
      - mysqldb
      - eureka-service
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
      - kafka

  email-service:
    image: app/email-service
    links:
      - eureka-service
      - gate-way-service
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
      - kafka
```

Proccess:

userService sends by Kafka message a token and the user email to the emailService. When emailService receives the message, it builds the email body. The body contains an URL in order to access to the service. emailService takes the URL from properties. The URL should contain the gatewayService host (and then the gateWayService will redirect to userService).

Currently, emailService gets the URL by a property like is:

```
user.service.endpoint=http://gate-way-service:8050:public/users/validateToken
```

I thought that the "gate-way-service" would be replaced by their host, but not.

The email contains http://gate-way-service:8050:public/users/validateToken, instead of http://gateWayService-IP:8050:public/users/validateToken

Is there a way to get the host/ip of the gatewayService dynamically? How should I do?

Comment: Your going to have to describe email service better. Are you using rest template? Ribbon or spring cloud load balancer?

Comment: Hi @spencergibb ! Let me explain better. userService sends by kafka message a token and the user email to the emailService. When emailService receive the message, the service builds the email body taking the URL from properties and sends it. The URL should contain the gatewayService host.
All the microservices are connected with eureka-services and gateway service

Comment: Try injecting `LoadBalancerClient` and call `loadBalancerClient.choose("gate-way-service")`.

Comment: @spencergibb doing that, the URL returned is http://735513b88ba8:8050, It has 735513b88ba8 instead of the IP address. Is there a way to get the address?

Comment: You need to configure registration to prefer IP address. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/3.0.1/reference/html/#spring-cloud-eureka-server-prefer-ip-address

Comment: @spencergibb still the same problem. Still sending the host insted of the IP address.

Comment: @spencergibb sorry, it works. The problem is that it gets the IP of the container(172.21.0.5) instad of the IP of Docker (192.168.99.1). Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: You either have to set it explicitly via an env var that is set by the platform or configure the guess that Spring Cloud makes to ignore private networks https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/3.0.1/reference/html/#ignore-network-interfaces

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb. In which service should I set the property spring: cloud.    inetutils.ignoredInterfaces:docker0,veth.*? In all services?

Comment: All the ones registering the wrong IP address